# AWS Quicksight - transfer ownership of a user resouce before deleting it by API

Tags: api, boto3, amazon-quicksight

When I am deleting a Quicksight user by AWS console, there is a option to transfer all the users resources to another user. However by API (boto3 delete_user), then I deleted the user, the resources stay orphaned. There is no option about transfer this resources. Does anyone has any idea about how I can handle that by APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following document addresses the question. It does refer to resource retrieval AFTER deletion but should be valid for PRE deletion too.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/quicksight-access-resource-deleted-user/

The referenced commands/apis are:

```
aws quicksight list-analyses
aws quicksight update-analysis-permissions
aws quicksight list-dashboards
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions
aws quicksight list-data-sets
aws quicksight update-data-set-permissions
aws quicksight list-data-sources
aws quicksight update-data-source-permissions
```