# Does AWS Quicksight / Boto3 direct API for transferring AWS QuickSight assets (DataSources, Dataset, and Dashboard) using some automated way

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, aws-quicksight-assets

I need to transfer AWS QuickSight assets (DataSources, Dataset, and Dashboard). I am looking for some automated way rather than doing it from was QuickSight portal managed assets.

Ref [link](https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/how-to-migrate-quicksight-dashboards-from-one-aws-account-to-another/5109).
I Have reference [this page](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/quicksight-access-resource-deleted-user) and this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055149/aws-quicksight-transfer-ownership-of-a-user-resouce-before-deleting-it-by-api) as well.

But I could not find any suitable example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/automate-and-accelerate-your-amazon-quicksight-asset-deployments-using-the-new-apis/14402

Here is part of the content
"Business intelligence (BI) and IT operations (BIOps) teams often need to automate and accelerate the deployment of BI assets to ensure business continuity. We heard that you wanted an automated and scalable way to deploy, back up, and replicate Amazon QuickSight 2 assets at scale so that BIOps teams within your organization can work in an agile manner.

Today, we are releasing six new QuickSight APIs to allow programmatic access to export and import QuickSight assets—dashboards, analyses, datasets including ingestion schedules, data sources, themes, and VPC configurations—across accounts and environments. These new APIs allow you to interact with a collection of assets in a lift-and-shift manner for deployment across QuickSight accounts, enable backup and restore, and support replication so you can automate workflows and achieve your desired infrastructure setup. These new capabilities bring greater agility to your BIOps teams, allowing you to automate and seamlessly integrate QuickSight assets into existing infrastructure.

Prior to this launch, you needed to have an in-depth understanding of QuickSight asset relationships and couldn’t deploy, back up, or replicate at scale in an automated manner. In this post, we cover the capabilities of the new APIs in detail and go over common use cases.

Export APIs

You can use the following APIs to initiate, track, and describe the export jobs that produce the bundle files from the source account. A bundle file is a zip file (with the .qs extension) that contains assets specified by the caller, and optionally all dependencies of the assets. The APIs are as follows:

StartAssetBundleExportJob – Use this asynchronous API to export an asset bundle file.
DescribeAssetBundleExportJob – Use this synchronous API to get the status of your export job. When successful, this API call response will have a presigned URL to fetch the asset bundle.
ListAssetBundleExportJobs – Use this synchronous API to list past export jobs. The list will contain both finished and running jobs from the past 15 days.

Import APIs

These APIs initiate, track, and describe the import jobs that take the bundle file as input and create or update assets in the destination account:

StartAssetBundleImportJob – Use this asynchronous API to start an import of an asset bundle file.
DescribeAssetBundleImportJob – Use this synchronous API to get the status of your import job.
ListAssetBundleImportJobs – Use this synchronous API to list past import jobs. The list will contain both finished and running jobs from the past 15 days."